# Is this possible to change the receipt format in woocommerce?

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, receipt

I am using Woocommerce. I am getting the receipt number on the payment page like the below image

```
wc_order_qs3VAezaTDgjk
```

[image]

I have to change the receipt format. Is this possible?

Comment: The receipt that you are displaying is not a transaction ID or some other ID but it is the order Key that can not be changed *(and should not be displayed)*, because it's made and used to secure for example the access to the Order received Page. But yes you could change the display, formatting that as you like, overriding the `thankyou` template. You can even display something else like a custom order number available using the hook `woocommerce_order_number` like in [those threads](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=woocommerce_order_number)

Comment: @LoicTheAztec, I don't know how I am getting that receipt number on my payment page. When I click proceed to checkout page then It's redirecting on payment gateway and there I am getting all this information

Comment: This due to your theme customization, as normally this is only displayed in the url as a variable like `…/checkout/order-received/1029/?key=wc_order_qs3VAezaTDgjk`, but not on the order received page itself.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec, When I click to proceed to checkout page then It's redirecting on a payment gateway and there I am getting this receipt but the URL is different https://invoices.paymentgateway.com/v1/t/inv_GpDcHW9jIFcx22.   (As of now URL is dummy)